# How to download DOJO widget (range slider) so I can run offline

Tags: dojo

Is there an easy way to download everything I need so I can use the range slider offline.  I don't care if it contains a lot of code I won't use.  It seems like this task is either way more difficult than it should be or more than likely, I've made it more difficult than it is.  Thanks,
Dale

Answer (score 1):

Err, download Dojo and save it for offline use?

- Download page

  http://dojotoolkit.org/download/
- Uncompressed Dojo source for development

  http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0/dojo-release-1.7.0-src.zip
- Compressed Dojo libraries

  http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0/dojo-release-1.7.0.zip

Comment: There's actually a lot more to it than that.  For example see this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356442/why-does-dojo-work-when-using-cdn-but-not-when-using-this-dojo-setlocalpath which helps, but doesn't quite get me all the way there.  Thanks.